# NP Problems with unique solution

Tags: complexity-theory, decision-problem, np, cryptography

Is there any class of NP problems that have one unique solution?
I'm asking that, because when I was studying cryptography I read about the knapsack and I found very interesting the idea.

Comment: You seem to be shaky on your terminology; NP problems can be arbitrarily easy, and they are usually decision problems (which *always* have a unique solution, yes or no); read more [at our reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/845/98). I assume you want NPO-hard problems with unique solutions?

Comment: Yes, I was meaning NP complete or NP hard, or whatever that is not in P... Sorry and thanks to point out

Comment: We don't know if NP-complete problems are not in P...

Answer (score 12):

Yes, the class is called [UP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UP_%28complexity%29) (the U standing for "unambiguous"). David points out in the comments that another answer is [US](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo%3aU#us).

UP: If $x \in L$, then there is exactly one "proof" ("witness", "certificate", "accepting path"). If $x \not\in L$, there are exactly zero "proofs".

US: If $x \in L$, then there is exactly one "proof". If $x \not\in L$, there may be zero proofs, or 2+ proofs, as long as there is not exactly one.

Comment: Or US, a different complexity class. (For UP machines, there is always at most one accepting path, for US there can be more than one but they only accept if there is exactly one.)